# Is this updateProduct right? (Express)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, file-upload, formidable

```
export const updateProduct = asyncHandler(async (req, res) =>{
const { id: productId } = req.params
const fieldsToUpdate = req.body

const product = await Product.findById(productId)

if (!product) {
    throw new CustomError("Product not found", 400)
}

const deletePhotos = await Promise.all(
    product.photos.map(async (elem, index) => {
        await s3FileDelete({
            bucketName:  config.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
            key: `products/${productId}/photo_${index + 1}.png`
        })
    })
)

await deletePhotos

const form = formidable({ multiples: true, keepExtensions: true });

form.parse(req, async function(err, fields, files) {
    if (err) {
        new CustomError(err.message || "something went wrong", 500)
    }

    console.log(fields, files);

    const imgArrayResp = Promise.all(
        Object.keys(files).map( async (file, index) => {
            const element = file[fileKey]
            console.log(element);

            const data = fs.readFileSync(element.filepath)

            const upload =  await s3FileUpload({
                bucketName: config.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
                key: `products/${productId}/photo_${index + 1}.png`,
                body: data,
                contentType: element.mimetype
            })

            // console.log(upload);
            return {
                secure_url: upload.Location
            }
        })
    )
    const imgArray = await imgArrayResp
    
    const updateFields = {
        photos: imgArray,
        ...fields
    }

    const updatedProduct = await Product.updateOne(productId, updateFields, {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
    })

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        updatedProduct
    })
})
})
```

I just want to verify my code is this code right?
just attempting to update the fields if given and delete outdated photographs.

Comment: where is fileKey defined ?, for the rest could work but look at the examples for more efficient solution